# Generating PDF from php generated HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, mpdf

Anyone can help me generating pdf using MPDF for the following code.

```
<table width="360" height="161" border="1" class="tablestyle">
<tr>
<td height="36" colspan="5" bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center" class="style6">ACADEMIC PERFORMANCE - <br />
UNIT TEST</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="89"><div align="center" class="style3 style8">SUBJECTS</div></td>
<td width="73"><div align="center" class="style9">No. Of Tests</div></td>
<td width="82"><div align="center" class="style9">Mark Obtained</div></td>
<td width="82"><div align="center" class="style9">Full Mark</div></td>
<td width="88"><div align="center" class="style9">12.5% of <br />Mark Scored</div></td>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td><span class="style7">&nbsp;<?php echo $row_dep['Subject'];?></span></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_dep['times'];?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_dep['score'];?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo $row_dep['fm'];?></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><?php echo  number_format($row_dep['score']/$row_dep['fm']*12.5,2); ?></div></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_dep = mysql_fetch_assoc($dep)); ?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center"><strong>Total</strong></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center"><?php echo $row_exe['ex'];?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center"><?php echo $row_unit['utotal'];?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center"><?php echo $row_unfm['ufm'];?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#ECE9D8"><div align="center"><strong><?php echo number_format($row_unit['utotal']/$row_unfm['ufm']*12.5,2); ?></strong></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div align="right"><strong>Grade:</strong></div></td>
<td><div align="center"><strong><?php 
$div=$row_unit['utotal']/$row_unfm['ufm']*100;
if  ($div>=90)
{
echo "A1";
}
    elseif($div>=80)
{
echo "A2"; 
}
elseif($div>=70)
{
    echo "B1"; 
}
elseif($div>=60)
{
    echo "B2"; 
}
elseif($div>=50)
{
    echo "C1"; 
}
elseif($div>=40)
{
echo "C2"; 
}
elseif($div>=33)
{
echo "D"; 
}
elseif($div>=21)
{
echo "<font color=red>E1</font>"; 
}            
else
{
    echo "<font color=red>E2</font>"; 
}
?></strong></div></td>
<td><strong><div align="center">Percentage</strong></div></td>
<td><strong><div align="center">
<?php
echo number_format($row_unit['utotal']/$row_unfm['ufm']*100,2);
?>%
</strong></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to put the above table inside `$html`, I have been trying with some samples given in the MPDF manual but could not figure out how to output. For example, for printing `<?php echo $row_dep['Name_of_Student'];?>` in `$HMTL` I know that I can use `'.$row_dep['Name_of_Student'].'` but when it comes to generating rows as I have here in between `<?php do { ?>` and `<?php } while ($row_dep = mysql_fetch_assoc($dep)); ?>` I don't know and could not produce the desired output.

Comment: Have you looked at output buffering (see `ob_start()`)?

Comment: @cimmanon No, I have no idea how to use `ob_start()`. I am new to php. Can this be done without using `ob_start())` function? As MPDF does not allow to use `<?php echo` inside `$html`, I want to know how I can output the above script in PDF using MPDF.

Comment: @cimmanon `ob_start()` does not work with the above code.

Comment: After two days I could solved my problem. It works with `ob_start` in combination with `include`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how this can be done...

```
<?php 
include("mpdf.php");

ini_set('memory_limit','3000M');//extending php memory
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4-L','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);//A4 size page in landscape orientation
$mpdf->SetHeader('Put your header here');
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;    // false is default
//$mpdf->SetWatermarkText("any text");
//$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
//$mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
//$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('logo.png');
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;


// Buffer the following html with PHP so we can store it to a variable later
ob_start();
?>
<?php include "yourphp.php";//The php page you want to convert to pdf
 // asasas?>

<?php 
$html = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

// send the captured HTML from the output buffer to the mPDF class for processing

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
//$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), 'mawiahl', 'password');//for password protecting your pdf

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```